# Converting exploded array into string

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, explode

In the project that I am creating, I have a mysql column that is an array of different pieces of data from the database.  These pieces of data have info that I want to display.  In order to separate these items in the array I used,

```
$get_query = mysql_query('Select array FROM data');
while($dataRow = mysql_fetch_assoc($getfrnd_query)) {
    $array = $dataRow['array'];
    if($array != "") {
        $data_from_array_column = explode("," $array);
        $getdata = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM info WHERE item = $data_from_array_column");
        //Then I used a mysql_fetch_assoc to get data based on the item.
    }
}
```

When I run this code, I get an error "Array to string conversion on the line with $getdata".
Is there any way to get this to work?

Thank you.

Comment: Where does `$data_from_array_column` come into play?

Comment: This code takes the data associated with each item from the array mysql column and will eventually display it.

Comment: That error means that `$data_from_array_column` is an array, but you are using it as a string.  Can you provide the code that generates it, or add `var_dump($data_from_array_column);` at the beginning of your code and post it so we can see it.

Comment: Showing your full code or reference taken from `$data_from_array_column` would shed a bit more light on the subject. ;-) Plus, "IF" anything, that should be wrapped in quotes. `WHERE item = '$data_from_array_column'");`

Comment: I just changed the name of the variable with the explode function to $data_from_array_column.  Would that fix my issue?

Comment: The problem is that [`explode`](http://us3.php.net/explode) returns an array, not a string.  In order to use the data from it, you need to either use [`implode`](http://us3.php.net/implode) to join the items in the array, or get one of the elements like this: `$data_from_array_column=$data_from_array_column[0]`.

Comment: Try what `SuperScript` said, and you will need to use quotes `WHERE item = '$data_from_array_column'");`

Comment: This semi-works.  Is there a way for me to return every item in this array rather than just the first one.

Comment: @user3513120: Yes, see my answer.  *(and if it works, accept me by clicking the little check mark!)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that [`explode`](https://www.php.net/explode) returns an array containing the strings in between the character(s) you used as a delimiter (`,` in your case), not a string.

PHP is getting mad because it doesn't know how to convert your array to a string automatically.  So, you will need to convert it yourself.  The options are:

1. You want to select the row where `item` is equal to the *nth* element in the array, `$data_from_array_column`.  If this is the case, you need to insert the following line of code after your explode:

`$data_from_array_column = $data_from_array_column[0];`

2. If you want to select where it matches *any* of the elements in the `$data_from_array_column` array, it will get more complicated.  You would need to add this line after the explode:

`$data_from_array_column = implode("' OR item='",$data_from_array_column);`

and change your query on the next line to:

`$getdata = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM info WHERE item='$data_from_array_column'");`

This will create a MySQL query that looks some thing like this:

`SELECT * FROM info WHERE item='foo' OR item='bar' OR item='bla'`